# Project Euler alternatives?

Tags: webapp-rec, project-euler

I have completed nearly fifty of the practice problems on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/), but I would like to move away from the pure mathematics, number theory, and programming practice problems for a bit and solve more practical mathematics problems for preparation of my future major (physics). However, I appreciate Project Euler's mechanism of presenting a problem and offering a PDF document with the solution only after the answer has been found.

Does something similar to this application exist?

Answer (score 0):

There are sites that post lists of programming challenges.

For example:

- [Jessica Ledbetter: Programming Challenges](https://web.archive.org/web/20110106161734/http://www.jessicaledbetter.com/programming-challenges/) (2010 Internet Archive)
- [8 Online Programming Contests That You Can Challenge Yourself To Win](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/8-onlineprogramming-contests-challenge-win/) (2010)

Comment: All these are nice sites, especially Programming Praxis and Code Chef, but I would like to lean toward mathematics-based practice sites instead of strictly programming and bit logic. I have tried searching Google for "mathematics practice problems" and "mathematics challenges" but have only found a single site that offers problems at a higher level than high school calculus.

Answer (score 0):

[Sphere Online Judge](http://www.spoj.pl/) is a great site filled with loads of programming puzzles

Comment: Link no longer resolves